# I am learing react.js but i am finding it difficult to understand how the react app will work when deployed?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I mean will it only serve the index.html file?But how can a client run that html file because it is not regular html file? and do i need to have a back end node to run it?
Actually i am unable to under stand the whole process.
In general client requests a html file and a server returns that html file to the client. 
But in case of react how index.html. Does the server return index.html plus all the components and then it gets rendered by the browser or does it come pre rendered from the server.

Comment: Welcome to React! Yes, basically it only requires the initial index file (assuming proper included element, script and link tags and server setup). then react, using the JS engine, handles the rest once your app's code is loaded by the visitor. So depending on how you plan to serve your react app you might have to configure your server to send the compiled react files to the user. Your question is very broad, so you may want to add more details if you need assistance. (e.g. server software, etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need a host to put your React application on. This can simply be a place where your files are accessible via HTTP (Amazon S3, Github Pages, a webhosting account, etc). A user then goes to a url, and that host will respond with your HTML file that might look something like this:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>A title here</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

When the browser loads this html file, it sees that script tag and then loads up the `src` of that script, making a request for an `app.js` on your host.  `app.js` may look something like this:

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'

function App() {
  return <h1>My App</h1>
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'))
```

The browser then executes that script, which creates the `<App/>` component, and puts it in the html node with id `app`, thereby rendering your react app.

No application code is required server side. Everyone gets the same HTML and Javascript, and the HTML the host provides is very basic providing an empty place to render your app, and a link to your React custom code. That's it.

---

I left out a part for simplicity, which is compilation. You write the javascript code above, but something like babel or webpack will take what you wrote, and load those dependencies (React, ReactDOM) and compile those JSX tags (`<h1>`, `<App/>`) into something the browser can understand. This creates (usually) a single large javascript file which is what gets put on your host for the browser to download. It includes React, any other npm libraries you want to use, and your custom application code all in one file.

Answer (score 1):

When you run the build command on your React app, it takes all the imported files (import ... from ...) and bundles them (this is what Webpack does). That index.html file has a script tag that reference to a big js file (that bundled one) with all the code: React, your component, the libs in node_modules, ..., everything. What that big script file is loaded in the browser it handle the whole construction of your app.